# How to bind a click event to a button when component is mounted vue js?

Tags: vue.js, addeventlistener, eventtrigger

I am using a third party app ([vue slick carousel](https://gs-shop.github.io/vue-slick-carousel/#/example/simple)) and I need to bind a click event to below button

```
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-arrow slick-next" style="display: block;">
    <svg...</svg>
</button>
```

So everytime I click this button a function gets triggered. This is what I tried in `mounted` and `created` life cycle, but didn't bind click event to it.

```
// console.log(document.querySelector(".slick-next")); // this returns element stated above

document.querySelector(".slick-next").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Works");
});
```

I tried using `setAttribute` hoped it works, but it didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/listening-to-next-buttons-click-of-vueslickcarousel-jh24x?file=/src/App.vue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect they're probably using stopPropagation on the button click inside the component then.

There might be another way around this depending on your needs:

```
<VueSlickCarousel @beforeChange="checkChange">
    ...
</VueSlickCarousel>
```

---

```
methods: {
    checkChange(oldSlideIndex, newSlideIndex) {
        if (newSlideIndex > oldSlideIndex) {
            console.log("Next button clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Another option might be to use the `<template #nextArrow="{ currentSlide, slideCount }"></template>` slot inside the Carousel tag and use your own button. You'd probably have to implement your own logic for setting the next slide if you went this route.

Answer (score -1):

You must to use the [events handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) of vuejs. Vuejs have many events for multiple cases.

For example in your case, you can use the event `v-bind:click` or simply `@click`. In documentation of [vue slick](https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel/blob/master/docs/API.md#events), show this examples, wich is essentially the same.

I attach an code snippet:

```
<template>
  <VueSlickCarousel ref="carousel">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    /*...*/
  </VueSlickCarousel>
  <button @click="showNext">show me the next</button>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      showNext() {
        this.$refs.carousel.next()
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but you didn't understand the question I believe.  The button is within a third party app and is already created without a click bind function. So I have to manually bind a click event when the app is loaded in DOM.

Comment: Thanks again, I appreciate it. 

I already saw this in documentation too, but can we do it anyway as I wanted on that  button without having to create another button and then hooking a method to it.

Comment: I guess using `@init` https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel/blob/master/docs/API.md#listening-to-events

Comment: same story as before ;)